# When I create a folder programmatically get the error "Invalid item data -- missing FileRef"

Tags: feature, folder

I am trying to add programmatically the desired Folder. I do the following

```
foreach (SPListItem reparto in reparti.Items)
{
  var folder = dl.Items.Add(dl.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl, SPFileSystemObjectType.Folder);
  folder["Title"] = "Test";
  folder.Update();
}
```

But I get the following error on update: `Invalid item data -- missing FileRef`

Why?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to create a folder, you have to specify its name in the `leafName` parameter. change your code to :

```
foreach (SPListItem reparto in reparti.Items)
{
     var folder = dl.Items.Add(
          dl.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl, 
          SPFileSystemObjectType.Folder, 
          "Test"
          );

     folder.Update();
}
```

If it can help, here a small utility method I wrote to create a full folder hierarchy :

```
/// <summary>
/// Provide utilities methods related to folder management
/// </summary>
public static class SPFolderUtilities
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Ensures the specified folder exists.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="list">The list where to create the folder.</param>
    /// <param name="subFolderPath">The sub folder path.</param>
    /// <returns>
    /// The existing <see cref="SPFolder"/> or a newly created if it did not exists.
    /// </returns>
    public static SPFolder EnsureFolder(SPList list, string subFolderPath)
    {
        Contract.Requires<ArgumentNullException>(list != null);
        Contract.Requires<ArgumentNullException>(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(subFolderPath));
        if (!IO.SPPathUtilities.IsFileOrFolderNameValid(subFolderPath, true))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Invalid characters in the file or folder name", "subFolderPath");
        }

        var folderPaths = subFolderPath.Split('/');

        var currentFolder = list.RootFolder;
        for (int i = 0; i < folderPaths.Length; i++)
        {
            currentFolder = list.ParentWeb.GetFolder(currentFolder.Url); // hacky refresh
            var subFolder = currentFolder.SubFolders.Cast<SPFolder>().FirstOrDefault(f => string.Compare(f.Name, folderPaths[i], true) == 0);
            if (subFolder == null)
            {
                var newFolderItem = list.Items.Add(currentFolder.ServerRelativeUrl, SPFileSystemObjectType.Folder, folderPaths[i]);
                newFolderItem.SystemUpdate();

                subFolder = newFolderItem.Folder;
            }
            currentFolder = subFolder;
        }
        return currentFolder;
    }
}
```

Comment: very nice utility function

Answer (score 4):

Yet another version how to create a folder including nested folders using SharePoint SSOM.

### How to create nested Folder using SharePoint SSOM

```
internal static class SPFolderExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Ensure SPFolder
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="web"></param>
    /// <param name="listTitle"></param>
    /// <param name="folderUrl"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static SPFolder CreateFolder(this SPWeb web, string listTitle, string folderUrl)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(folderUrl))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("folderUrl");
        var list = web.Lists.TryGetList(listTitle);
        return CreateFolderInternal(list, list.RootFolder, folderUrl);
    }


    private static SPFolder CreateFolderInternal(SPList list, SPFolder parentFolder, string folderUrl)
    {
        var folderNames = folderUrl.Split(new char[] {'/'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        var folderName = folderNames[0];

        var curFolder =
            parentFolder.SubFolders.Cast<SPFolder>()
                        .FirstOrDefault(
                            f =>
                            System.String.Compare(f.Name, folderName, System.StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ==
                            0);
        if (curFolder == null)
        {
            var folderItem = list.Items.Add(parentFolder.ServerRelativeUrl, SPFileSystemObjectType.Folder,
                                            folderName);
            folderItem.SystemUpdate();
            curFolder = folderItem.Folder;
        }


        if (folderNames.Length > 1)
        {
            var subFolderUrl = string.Join("/", folderNames, 1, folderNames.Length - 1);
            return CreateFolderInternal(list, curFolder, subFolderUrl);
        }
        return curFolder;
    }
}
```

Key points:

- Ability to create a nested folder(s)
- Existing folders will not be affected

Usage

The below example demonstrates how to create the following folder structure under `Documents` library:

```
Orders
   |
   Orders A
      |
      Orders A1
```

Example:

```
var folder = web.CreateFolder("Documents", "Orders3/Orders A/Orders A1");
```