# In a SharePoint List I cannot see items that are in a folder

Tags: development, list, list-view, folder

I have a sharepoint list (Not Library), where I am programmatically adding in a folder:

```
SPList list = web.Lists[ListID];                    
SPFolder parent = list.RootFolder;
SPFolder child = parent.SubFolders.Add(FolderName);
parent.Update();
child.Update();
```

This adds in a folder to the library, to which I then add in a listitem:

```
SPListItem item = list.AddItem(child.Url, SPFileSystemObjectType.File);
item[DefaultSettings.S_COL_Title] = "New title";
item.Update();
```

The net result of this is that the item is added with no errors, but when I go to my library I do not see the item.

If I go into the view and change the option under Foldering from `"Show items inside folders"` to `"Show all items without folders"`, my newly added item is then visible. 
Also if I manually type in the url to the folder, I can see the item.

So I know the item is there, and that it is in its folder.

I want the folder to display in the view, and if I click on the folder to then see the item.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What are you naming your folder? Folders starting or ending with underscore "_" will be hidden from the UI

Comment: Thats an interesting point Robert, I'm calling it "HELLO_WORLD", so there is an underscore in the name. Will this have an effect?

Comment: I just tried it without the underscore and it still has the same issue. :'(

Comment: No it should not have any effect if not in beginning or end.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was right here on sharepoint.stackexchange.com:
[When I create a folder programmatically get the error "Invalid item data -- missing FileRef"](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/42016/when-i-create-a-folder-porgrammatically-get-the-error-invalid-item-data-miss)

For those that don't want to click a link :D here's the relevant code:

```
/// <summary>
/// Ensures the specified folder exists.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="list">The list where to create the folder.</param>
/// <param name="subFolderPath">The sub folder path.</param>
/// <returns>
/// The existing <see cref="SPFolder"/> or a newly created if it did not exists.
/// </returns>
public static SPFolder EnsureFolder(SPList list, string subFolderPath)
{
    Contract.Requires<ArgumentNullException>(list != null);
    Contract.Requires<ArgumentNullException>(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(subFolderPath));
    if (!IO.SPPathUtilities.IsFileOrFolderNameValid(subFolderPath, true))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Invalid characters in the file or folder name", "subFolderPath");
    }

    var folderPaths = subFolderPath.Split('/');

    var currentFolder = list.RootFolder;
    for (int i = 0; i < folderPaths.Length; i++)
    {
        currentFolder = list.ParentWeb.GetFolder(currentFolder.Url); // hacky refresh
        var subFolder = currentFolder.SubFolders.Cast<SPFolder>().FirstOrDefault(f => string.Compare(f.Name, folderPaths[i], true) == 0);
        if (subFolder == null)
        {
            var newFolderItem = list.Items.Add(currentFolder.ServerRelativeUrl, SPFileSystemObjectType.Folder, folderPaths[i]);
            newFolderItem.SystemUpdate();

            subFolder = newFolderItem.Folder;
        }
        currentFolder = subFolder;
    }
    return currentFolder;
}
```

@Steve B: You sir are a legend.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following code snippet to create a folder in custom list and add new item in the new folder.

```
 
 using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://sp2013/sites/team/"))
{
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
        SPList list = web.Lists.TryGetList("CustomList");
        SPListItem folder = list.Items.Add(list.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl, SPFileSystemObjectType.Folder);
        folder["Title"] = "New Folder";
        folder.Update();
        list.Update();
```

`string folderUrl = folder.Folder.ServerRelativeUrl;
        SPListItem item = list.AddItem(folderUrl, SPFileSystemObjectType.File);
        item["Title"] = "New title";
        item.Update();
}}`