# Exception when adding folder to document library

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document-library

I have a script where I locate a document library and try to add a folder to it, however, it fails. This is my current failing script:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb($completeUrl)

$DocumentLibrary = $completeUrl + "/DocumentLibrary"

$site = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($DocumentLibrary)

$website = $site.OpenWeb()

$list = $website.GetList($DocumentLibrary)

$newFolder = $list.AddItem("", [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFileSystemObjectType]::Folder)
$newFolder["Title"] = "Weekly"
$newFolder.Update()
```

The exception that I get is: `Exception calling "Update" with "0" argument(s): "Invalid item data -- missing FileRef."`

Any hints?

Comment: See this answer maybe? http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/42016/when-i-create-a-folder-programmatically-get-the-error-invalid-item-data-miss

Comment: is there a particular reason that you are getting to site by document library url first, then again from getLists? I think you can just directly get  to document library using just this: $list = $website.GetList($DocumentLibrary)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just tested and this works for me:

```
$DocumentLibrary = "Yourlibrary's Full Url here"
$list = $web.GetList($DocumentLibrary)
$folder = $list.Items.Add("", [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFileSystemObjectType]::Folder,"Weekly")
$folder.Update()
```

Comment: You are right, that seems like a smarter (and easier) way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set an empty string as the first argument for AddItem(). Look at the reference on MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee558947.aspx

In your case, you would have to set the server-relative url of the list as the first methode-argument. E.g.

```
$newFolder = $list.AddItem($website.ServerRelativeUrl + "/DocumentLibrary", [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFileSystemObjectType]::Folder)
```